# Rational algebraic numbers

Tags: number-theory

A polynomial with integer coefficients is an expression of the form: $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n−1}x^{n−1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0,$$
where $a_n, a_{n−1},\ldots,a_1,a_0$ are integers and $a_n\ne 0$.

A zero of the polynomial is a $c\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(c)=0$.

A real number is said to be algebraic if it is a zero of some polynomial with integer coefficients

1) Show that every rational number is algebraic.

2) Show that if $a$, $b$ and $k$ are positive integers, then the $k$th root of $a/b$ is algebraic.

I have no idea what to do, this is an advanced problem, I'm just curious to the solution.